# How can I save checkbox state to my database?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mongodb

I'm trying to create a Todo-list app using (nodejs,ejs...) so for every todo I create a checkbox. If someone finishes his job and uses the button bin recycle to delete it, I save that using MongoDB but I've a problem when checking. When I reload the page this checked box disappears. In other words, my question is: **How to save the information in my database if the checkbox is checked?**

```html
<div class="box">

  <% DoList.forEach(function(elem) { %>
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <p class=i tems>
        <%=elem %>
      </p>
      <form action="/delete" method="post">
        <button class="delete" type="submit" name="delete" value='<%=elem%>'><img src="stylee/bin.png" alt="bin cycle"></button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you try to search on google? SO is not a free service code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please refer to the guidelines of how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your checkbox inside the form and add something like
$yourcheckbox= isset($_POST['yourcheckboxname'])?1:0;
1 mean check 0 mean uncheck